# Getent Hosts For Port 1519/tcp -iptables 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, iptables, viewports

I have a scenario:
i will have to protect my network from unsolicited access from my DMZ machine, configure node-A to allow new connections on port 1915/tcp from hosts (obtained by 'getent hosts node-B') but disallow any other access from or to node-B.

I am unable to find any port details by 'getent hosts node-B', how to perform this using iptables?

[image]

Comment: This is a pretty easy set of iptables rules, have you tried setting up the firewall already?

Comment: there is no firewall setup. I would like to achieve it via either firewall/iptables.